# Java HttpClient cannot parse IP address in Android

Tags: java, android, httpclient

Edited: fixing mistake in the uri

I'm using an instance of org.apache.http.client.HttpClient to connect to a REST based web service on a local network:

```
String uri = "http://192.168.0.101:8888/someinstance/someresource?name=blah&age=blah";
final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

This is working fine on an HTC Incredible with 2.3.3 but on an HTC Wildfire with 2.2.1 leads to an IllegalArgumentException with the message: Target host must not be null.

If I use a uri using a host name rather than IP address the problem does not occur. For example the following executes with no errors:

```
String uri = "http://www.somehost.com:8888/someinstance/someresource?name=blah&age=blah";
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong. Assuming I have to use an IP address is there any way round this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Snap, Same issue on my Galaxy Nexus. Still not found a solution to this yet!